# How to convert an optional to a non-optional and then call it?

Tags: swift

```
class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    
    var viewModel: PostViewModel? {
        didSet { configure() }
    }
    
    weak var delegate: FeedCellDelegate?

//If post is an optional I get an error at var videoURL saying "Value of optional type 'Post?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'videoURL' of wrapped base type 'Post'." If I change var post to a non optional in order to call post.videoURL then I get an error in super.init saying "Property 'self.post' not initialized at super.init call"
    

var post: Post?
        var videoUrl: URL { post.videoURL }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        backgroundColor = .black
ddSubview(postImageView)
        postImageView.anchor(top: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, right: rightAnchor,
                             paddingTop: 10)
        postImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        
        
}
```

Comment: Your post is a little unclear to me. Where is it going wrong? Which line? Perhaps only show the relevant code and show the error.

Comment: just made edits. Please check.

Comment: I would recommend you pause and spend some time to learn about optionals. They're a fundamental feature to Swift, and you'll find yourself increasingly confused, frustrated and slowed down if you just try to "power through". I would suggest reading the Swift Programming Language ("tSPL") through and through: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: I have updated my answer and I agree very much with @Alexander on that understanding optionals is essential for Swift.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to convert an optional to a non-optional. You can read a lot about them in the [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html). The first method is optional binding:

```swift
let optionalInt: Int? = 5

print(type(of: optionalInt)) // Prints Optional<Int> - At this moment, the content of the optionalInt variable MIGHT be nil

if let unwrappedInt = optionalInt { // If optionalInt is NOT nil, this statement will be true and I enter the if-block
    print(unwrappedInt) // Prints 5 - Now I know for sure that unwrappedInt is not nil
    print(type(of: unwrappedInt)) // Prints Int - Not optional anymore
}
```

You could also use a `guard` statement to accomplish the same, without nesting:

```swift
let optionalInt: Int? = 5

print(type(of: optionalInt)) // Prints Optional<Int> - At this moment, the content of the optionalInt variable MIGHT be nil

guard let unwrappedInt = optionalInt else { return }

print(unwrappedInt) // Prints 5 - Now I know for sure that unwrappedInt is not nil (otherwise it retuns)
print(type(of: unwrappedInt)) // Prints Int - Not optional anymore
```

Another method is [optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html). You *could* use force unwrapping (i.e. `optionalInt!`), but you shouldn't unless you know for certain that the value isn't `nil`, and isn't going to be `nil`. Force unwrapping is considered **bad practice** as this might lead to force unwrapping a `nil` value (which causes your app to crash).

**EDIT:**

In your case, `post` is optional. The use it somewhere else as a non-optional, you could use optional chaining. For example: `var videoUrl: URL? { post?.videoURL }`

Comment: The only problem with post?.videoURL is since URL is defined as a non optional in other areas of my code, it causes it to give an error. It fixes with writing var videoUrl: URL? {post?.videoURL} but gives error in other areas of code. I cant change the other areas because I am using the putFile method from firebase that requires it to be a non optional.

Comment: Okay! Good news! I figured it out. I am now calling videoURL in my code from a different file where I declared URL as a non optional. Now, it allows me to call it in this file and doesn't give me an error during initialization.

Comment: @LooneyTunes Glad to hear it's working! However, you can use one of the methods mentioned above to unwrap `videoUrl` to be non-optional as well, before you are calling your Firebase method.  :)